# Как найти и изменить значение в БД? SQLite

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Работаю с БД SQLite. Дополнительно работаю с ботом в ВКонтакте. Так вот, я не могу понять, как сделать команду, которая будет изменять значение с БД по поиску другого значения. То есть, есть команда для бота - /ник, где есть два значения. /ник `[Пользователь]`, где пользователь это имя, которое находится в БД. И /ник `[Пользователь]` `[Ник]`, где ник это значение, которое нужно указать для изменения в БД. Вот, как я это всё представил:

```
first_name   last_name   nickname
Вася         Петров      NULL
```

Пишу команду для бота: /ник Вася (либо Петров) VasyaPetrov

```
first_name   last_name   nickname
Вася         Петров      VasyaPetrov
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как это сделать.

Comment: можете уточнить суть вопроса? С чем конкретно возникли затруднения - с изменением данных в БД или с VK API?

Comment: @MaxU. БД. Со стороный Vk, идёт просто запрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

если вопрос в том как изменить существующую запись в SQLite DB, то это можно сделать при помощи `UPDATE ...`:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect("CaptureBotDB.db")
cur = conn.cursor()

sql = """UPDATE ListMembers SET nickname = %s WHERE id = %s"""
cur.execute(sql, (nicjname, record_id))
```

PS менять записи для всех `Вась` или для всех `Петровых` опасно. Представьте что в вашей БД 30 записей с фамилией Петров - для всех этих записей вы перепишете поле `nickname`. Поэтому в таких случаях лучше всегда иметь уникальный столбец - первичный ключ (`identifier` или сокращенно `id`) и обращаться к записям по `id`.

Comment: Н да, тогда лучше по ID. Вопрос: `cur.execute(sql, (nicjname, record_id))` - Вот тут как мне можно указать значение из команды? `/ник [ID] [Nick]`

Comment: @hoojpop, присвойте соответствующие значения переменным nickname и record_id

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо. Сейчас попробую.